# Base64 encode file and OutOfMemory error

Tags: android, zip, base64, out-of-memory

I have .zip file which I have to Base64 encode before uploading to the server. Given file can be up to 20 mb, which causes OutOfMemory exception. 
 I use this code:

```
public String encodeZipToBase64(File zip) {

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    byte fileContent[] = new byte[1024];
    try 
    {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(zip);
        while(fin.read(fileContent) >= 0) {
             sb.append(Base64.encodeToString(fileContent, Base64.DEFAULT)); //exception here
        }
    } catch(OutOfMemoryError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sb.toString();

}
```

Exception occurs on appending to StringBuilder. What can I do to resolve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the HTTP request `OutputStream` as an argument and write to it directly inside your read loop, instead of buffering the entire request as a `StringBuilder` in memory.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it is the only way. I just have existing rest apis, written before me, which are not likely to change :(